# How can i produce an array of n random integers that are both positive and negative

Tags: python, arrays, random, printing, stdio

I wanted to produce an array of n random integers that are both positive and negative. For example if i put in 4 it would produce [1,-2,-4,3]

```
import stdio
import sys
import random

n = int(input(sys.argv[0]))
y = n * -1

randomlist = []
for i in range(0,n):
    arr = random.randint(n, y)
    randomlist.append(arr)
print(randomlist)


sum = 0
for i in randomlist:
    sum += i

avg = sum/x
print("Average is",avg)
print("Max value is", max(randomlist))
print("Min value is", min(randomlist))
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

use randrange function instead

```
import random

random.randrange(y,n) # line 11
```

it should satisfy your need, and edit your code line 19 to `avg = sum/len(randomlist)`

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Python documentation about randint function.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#functions-for-integers

> random.randint(a, b)
> Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b. Alias for randrange(a, b+1).

Firstly, you have *a* and *b* arguments, and then *a* <= *b*. And in your case, *a* is more than *b*.

In your code would be like that, once *y* <= *n*:

```
arr = random.randint(y, n)
```

In second place, x is not defined. But as you wanna the average, so divide by *n*, like this `avg = sum/n`

Answer (score 0):

This will give you want you need here:

```
import random
import sys

n = int(input(sys.argv[0]))
y = n * -1
rand_list = random.sample(range(y, n), n)
```

You can go on with your mean, max and min:

```
print('Mean of list: ', sum(rand_list)/len(rand_list))
print('Max value: ', max(rand_list))
print('Min value: ', min(rand_list))
```